# Scala: what has been the desired design consideration for the null instantiation in the example

Tags: scala, variables

Or simply asked WHY ?
It simply does not seems logical ...

```
if ( null.asInstanceOf[String]  == null )  println 
("null.asIstanceOf[String] is null")

println ("BUT !!!")

if ( null.asInstanceOf[Double] == 0.0 ) println ( 
"null.AsInstanceOf[Double] is 0 !!" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually explained explicitly in the [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/). Please, have a look at [Section 6.3 *The **Null** value*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#the-null-value), which says this:

> The `null` value is of type `scala.Null`, and thus conforms to every reference type.
>   It denotes a reference value which refers to a special `null` object.
>   This object implements methods in class `scala.AnyRef` as follows:
>
> - […]
> - `asInstanceOf[T]` returns the default value of type `T`.

The default value for any subtype of `AnyRef` is `null`, the default value for subtypes of `AnyVal` is type-specific, but usually some type-specific neutral value, such as `0` for `Int`, `Long`, etc., `0.0` for `Float` and `Double`, and `false` for `Boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

A `Double` is a primitive type so *cannot* be `null`; quoting from the [2.13 Standard Library Reference](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Double.html):

> `Double`, a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point number (equivalent to Java's `double` primitive type)

A `String` on the other hand is of course a fully fledged object and so can be `null`.

As an aside, [you probably shouldn't be using `null` in your Scala code anyway](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/best-practice-eliminate-null-values-from-code-scala-idioms).

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `asInstanceOf` either.

Comment: `Double` is *not* a "primitive type". There are no primitive types in Scala. `Double` is a subtype of `AnyVal`, and thus also called a *value type*.